# Cannot boot ubuntu after remove failed data disk (system on different disk)

Tags: boot, hard-drive, disk, disk-utility

Our Ubuntu server has four hard disks, but we didn't make them a RAID. Yesterday, one of the disk was reported to be failing, and this disk was `/dev/sdb` and was mounted as `/data` (was used to store data), but the server cannot boot up after we remove this disk. We tried umount it or deleted it in the 'Disk utility', but didn't work.

Is there any way to just remove this disk and avoid re-installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bios is failing to boot, which means it's one of two problems:

1. The boot was installed to your data disk, solution: install grub to sda following this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Purging_.26_Reinstalling_GRUB_2
2. Your bios requires you to have a full set of hard drives and removing one has scewered up it's internal disk reporting mechanism. this will require you to use the bios disk management tools to sort it out.

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed the bios' problem. I changed several configurations of the bios, and IT REALLY BOOTS! Thanks very much for saving me a lot of time for reinstalling the system.

Comment: Do you remember what the configurations where that you changed? (and please up vote)